# jQuery plugin for quick navigation through posts using keys

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

As in facebook, we can navigate the posts by using the 'J' and 'K' keys, I want a jQuery plugin to do the same thing for my website. My logic is that I name the headings of the posts as 1,2,3,4... and on pressing the 'J' or 'K' keys it will scroll automatically to the respective named headings. I am unable to code that. I need a plugin for that. I tried to  google it but cannot phrase a term for the search. Any help is appreciated in advance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want some extensions, the closest to what you're doing sound like [this](https://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/) or perhaps [this](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout).

EDIT: Or perhaps [PageScroller](http://pagescroller.com/).

But if you don't mind doing even just a little coding, JQuery has most of what you need built right in, and you could write your own extension. Something like:

```
$(document).on('keypress', function(ev)
    {
        if (ev.which == '106')
        {
            $('html,body').scrollTop($("#nextPost").offset().top);
        } else if (ev.which == '107')
        {
            $('html,body').scrollTop($("#prevPost").offset().top);
        }
    });
```

Shorter version:

```
$(document).on('keypress',function(e)
{
    id = (e.which == '106') ? getNextPost() :
         (e.which == '107') ? getPrevPost() : undefined;
    if (id) $('html,body').scrollTop($(id).offset().top);
}
```

You could just replace #nextPost and #prevPost with functions which keep track of which post is "active." I often start my js files by defining tiny utility extensions like:

```
$.extend({
    postRegister : {
        registry : '#defaultInitiallyActivePost',
        next : function() {
            this.registry = $(this.registry).next('.post').attr('id');
            return this.registry;
        },
        prev : function() {
            this.registry = $(this.registry).prev('.post').attr('id');
            return this.registry;
        }
    }
});
```

EDIT: If you want the page to detect when the user has manually scrolled to a different post, you can just add a function that checks where the scrollbar currently is, cycles through the post elements on the page, checking their offsets to determine which post is being looked at.

Answer (score 0):

Well instead of numbers i would use certain DOM elements as jumping points. Besides that it should be easy to implement. Listen to the keyboard events and use scrollTo() and position() to do the magic.

Take a look at http://firedev.com/jquery.keynav/. I guess you could change the trigger keys.

Or google https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+keyboard+navigation+plugin&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: the plugin is fine...but in my case, when user scrolls to another post, and presses the 'j' key, it would not scroll to the next post but to the post triggered by the script....I hope you understand.(difficult to explain though) anyway, thaks for the help

Comment: Actually i don't understand. Maybe you mean the user is redirected to another page, or something is loaded via AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you are after, prehaps my [keynavigator plugin](http://nekman.github.io/keynavigator/) could help you.
Could you please show us some code or a example of what you are after?